# how to get JSON object by its parent key

Tags: javascript, json

if you look at this:

```
    [
    {
        "Option1Value": 1,
        "Options2": [
            {
                "Option2Value": 2,
                "Options3": [
                    {
                        "Option3Value": 3,
                        "Options4": [
                            {
                                "Option4Value": 4,
                                "Options5": [
                                    {
                                        "Option5Value": 5,
                                        "Product": [
                                            {
                                                "title","text"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what i want is to ask in JAVASCRIPT is:
can i get the Options3 nodes only by typing something like
Option1Value[value=1].Options2.Option2Value[value=2].Options3

no what i need to do is
Option1Value[0].Options2.Option2Value[0].Options3

is there as solution???

Comment: You can do this only in loop/iterator with condition statement.

Comment: are you sure? anything with node.js or anything i can make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do ,but what about something like this? Of course it depends on an Array or Object that you are going to work with...

```
 var opts = {};
     opts["2"] = arr[0]["Options2"][0]; // arr is your Array that is shown above
     opts["3"] = opts["2"]["Options3"][0];
     opts["4"] = opts["3"]["Options4"][0];
     opts["5"] = opts["4"]["Options5"][0];

  console.log(opts["3"]);
```

Comment: Sorry ,but I am lost right now. Properties OptionXValue are numbers and not Arrays so you can't do `Option1Value[...]["something"]`. Do you want to from us to change the structure of your JSON / JS Object?

Comment: Well ,but then you can't do this `Option1Value[value=1].Options2.Option2Value[value=2].Options3` or `Option1Value[0].Options2.Option2Value[0].Options3` because as I said above `Option1Value' is a Number.